# Como obter data atual com o horário em js?

Tags: javascript

Como obter data atual com o horario em js?

Preciso saber quantos dias correram após certa data. Estou usando o momentjs

```
var start = moment( "2016/06/17" );
var end = moment( new Date() );
var time = date_start.to(date_end);
console.log( moment.duration(time, 'days').humanize());
```

O meu problema, é que para o mesmo dia, eu preciso da diferença de horas da data. Só que os horario está zerado, então a diferença é igual a zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vc pode usar a função diff do momentjs.E ao criar um novo moment() vc já esta criando ele com a data atual.

**[EDITADO]**

Caso você queira que o texto apareça em português basta adicionar a biblioteca pt-br.js e colocar como primeiro comando do js moment.locale('pt-BR');

```js
moment.locale("pt-BR");
var start = moment("2016-06-17T09:00:00");
var end = moment();

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
console.log(moment.duration(end.diff(start,true)).humanize());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!!